# Failed to execute SP with error PLS-00201

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I've stored procedure called CAL_TAX which create by schema EMP_DBA, right now I want to grant execute right on this SP to user USER1. I've execute below statement:

```
CREATE USER USER1 IDENTIFIED BY USER1234;
GRANT CONNECT TO USER1;
GRANT RESOURCE TO USER1;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO USER1;
GRANT EXECUTE ON EMP_DBA.CAL_TAX TO USER1;

DECLARE
CURSOR C1 IS SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES;
CMD VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
FOR C IN C1 LOOP
CMD:='GRANT SELECT ON ' || C.TABLE_NAME || ' TO USER1';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CMD;
END LOOP;
END;
```

When I connect as USER1 and execute SP CAL_TAX, I received below error messages. Can anyone help me on this ? I've no problem to execute SP if connect as EMP_DBA

```
BEGIN CAL_TAX; END;

         *
ERROR AT LINE 1:
ORA-06550: LINE 1, COLUMN 7:
PLS-00201: IDENTIFIER 'CAL_TAX' MUST BE DECLARED
ORA-06550:LINE 1, COLUMN 7:
PL/SQL: STATEMENT IGNORED
```

This is the part of the SP CAL_TAX.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CAL_TAX
AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either specify the owner of the SP:

```
BEGIN emp_dba.cal_tax; END;
```

or, you can create a public synonym:

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM cal_tax FOR emp_dba.cal_tax;
```

or you can create a private synonym for each user:

```
CONNECT user1/pw
CREATE SYNONYM cal_tax FOR emp_dba.cal_tax;
```

Once the synonym is created, your original BEGIN..END block should work.

Comment: BEGIN CAL_TAX; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 
ORA-06512: at "EMP_DBA.CAL_TAX", line 111 
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: I can run the SP with USER1 once specified EMP_DBA schema in SP

Comment: Need to see the source for your SP to know for sure, but it seems as if you're referencing a table you don't have appropriate permissions on.  Are you perchance updating a table at line 111?